# For each loop output to displayed as list

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub search()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A50")
        If cell.Value = 1 Then
       
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to extract the cell address whose value is equal to 1 for range A1:A50

The output should be shown as table in the excel
eg
in the Range("A1:A50") if the total cell having value equal to 0 is 3 and lies in A5, A11 and A20. I want the output displayed as list in excel cell.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A5 |  |
| A11 |  |
| A20 |  |

Comment: It is possible to share more details on the line ``` Range("A14").Offset(0, 1) = cell.Address ```

Comment: `Range("A14").Offset(0, 1)` overwrites the same cell. If you want a list starting in B14 and going downwards, then perhaps `Range("B14").Offset(i).Value = cell.Address`, then `i = i + 1`.

Comment: I want to know after "then" what code I should give to get the output as list as shown in the table above.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, using your existing code, first add `r=1` line before your `For Each cell In Range("A1:A50")`. Then after your `If cell.Value = 1 Then` ... `range("B" & r).Value = cell.address(0, 0):r=r+1`. This will put the column A cell address which has value 1 in column B. The thing which I don't understand is "_if the total cell having value equal to **0** is 3_". Is that typo ? Actually you mean is 1 not 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try with the following commented code

```
Sub Search()

    With Range("A1:A50") 'reference wanted range
        
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, 1) > 0 Then ' chaeck if the referenced range has any cell whose value is "1"            
        
            ReDim ones(1 To .Rows.Count) As String 'initialize an array size to the referened range rows number
            
            Dim nOnes As Long
                nOnes = 0
                
                Dim cell As Range
                    For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) 'loop thorugh referenced range cells containing numbers only
                        If cell.Value = 1 Then
                            nOnes = nOnes + 1 'update n° of found cells matching wanted criteria
                            ones(nOnes) = cell.Address(False, False) 'store found cell address in array
                        End If
                    Next
                
                        If nOnes > 0 Then 'if any cell content matched wanted criteria
                        
                            ReDim Preserve ones(1 To nOnes) ' resize the found cells addresses array to the actual n° of found adresses
                            
                            .ClearContents 'clear referenced range content
                            
                            .Resize(nOnes).Value = Application.Transpose(ones) ' fill referenced range first cells with the found addresses
                            
                        End If
        End If

    End With
    
End Sub
```

this will overwrite column A values, as per your wording

should you want to store the addresses in another column, just change the `If nOnes > 0 Then` clause as follows:

```
                    If nOnes > 0 Then 'if any cell content matched wanted criteria
                    
                        ReDim Preserve ones(1 To nOnes) ' resize the found cells addresses array to the actual n° of found adresses
                        
                        With .Offset(, 1) ' reference referenced range offseted by one column to the right
                            .ClearContents 'clear referenced range content
                            
                            .Resize(nOnes).Value = Application.Transpose(ones) ' fill referenced range first cells with the found addresses
                        End With
                        
                    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub nbcnb()
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
i = -1
For Each cell In Range("A1:A5")
If cell.Value = 1 Then
i = 1 + i
Range("A14").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Address
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?